# Recipe microdata to JSON conversion with cook/prep/total time

Tags: php, json, microdata

I'm working on some PHP code to convert recipe microdata to JSON. I'm stumped on how to convert prep/cook/total time values to JSON. Maybe the solution is really simple? I'd love your help.

Here's an example of successful conversion of the following microdata:

```
<span itemprop="recipeCategory">Pasta</span>
<span itemprop="recipeCuisine">Italian</span>
```

to JSON:

```
'recipeCategory'       => array( 'span', 'itemprop', 'recipeCategory' ),
'recipeCuisine'       => array( 'span', 'itemprop', 'recipeCuisine' ),`
```

Here's where I'm stumped. How do I represent the following microdata in JSON, given that the value is represented between quotes (datetime="VALUE HERE")?

```
<time itemprop="prepTime" datetime="PT10M">10 mins</time> 
<time itemprop="cookTime" datetime="PT20M">20 mins</time> 
<time itemprop="totalTime" datetime="PT30M">30 mins</time>
```

Thank you, 
K

Comment: What is constraining you on the JSON end? Can't you just use "PT10M", "10 mins", "10 minutes", "00:10:00", or any other representation you like?

Comment: Hi! I need to use the PT10M format, but I'm not sure how to pull it from the microformatting for JSON.

Comment: You don't show how you got the result in your question. Are you using `DOMDocument`? `SimpleXML`? Something else?